# Importing non duplicates into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Question... I have two databases, let's say the first one is called `people1` and contains a table called `PF1` which has columns `first, last, middle, address, city, state, zip, phone, DOB`.

The second database is called `consumers` and has a table called `consumer1` with identical columns. Both databases don't have a PK but are indexed on first, middle, address, city, state and DOB.

I'd like the first database to become the main database with combined data from both databases, but I do not want to import any duplicate data, which the duplicate value would be an identical match on what columns are indexed in both databases.

Is there something I can run via the regular GUI importer to accommodate that, or do I have to just dump everything together and de-dupe it as a whole. Using SQL Server 2012 also...  thanks. Also and tsql examples would be awesome...

Comment: Are your tables on the same server? Why are you wanting to use the import wizard?

Comment: yes they are and that's the only way I know how to :/

Comment: OK, looks like you have some answers to try out -- let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to limit the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO people1.dbo.PF1
SELECT *
FROM consumers.dbo.consumer1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM people1.dbo.PF1 b
                  WHERE a.first = b.first
                    AND a.middle = b.middle
                    AND a.address = b.address
                    AND a.city = b.city
                    AND a.state = b.state
                    AND a.DOB = b.DOB)
```

If the databases are on different servers that can't be linked, importing the full table temporarily and then performing the above `INSERT` would work, otherwise using both tables as data sources in an `SSIS/Data Tools` package you could combine them and remove duplicates in one step.

Comment: they are on the same server. I'll give that a shot.. Thank you.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

with the "Import data" wizard, select "write a query to specify data transfer".
at this point you can merge the two tables from the two databases and remove the duplicates within your query and before importing the data